# Is there a way to add default params to sql procedure that has input/output params?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have this code:

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc(
            id IN NUMBER, 
            optional_txt IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, 
            random_pct OUT NUMBER
            )
    IS BEGIN
        random_pct := 101;      
    END myProc;
```

I want to call this procedure using only the required input param (id) like below:

```
myProc(id, random_pct);
```

However I get this error: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'myProc'`

If I remove the output param, it works fine as below:

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc(
            pn_random_id IN NUMBER, 
            pn_optional_txt IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
            )
    IS BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('Proc created.');
    END myProc;
```

(I called it like this):

```
myProc(id);
```

How can I make this work if I need the output param as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function instead of procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function myfunction(
            pn_random_id IN NUMBER, 
            pn_optional_txt IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
            ) return NUMBER
    IS BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('Proc created.');
      return  1; -- return value you need
    END myProc;
```

than you can call it

```
declare
  v_result number;
begin
  v_result := myfunction(1);
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi there! Appreciate your quick response. I tried it out and it works :) So I take it there's no way to use a procedure for this case?

Comment: that's right. if you think about it properly, it doesn't make sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well a function rather than a procedure is  the better solution. But you can use your original procedure and call with just the two parameters. But you need to change the call to named parameters rather than positional.

```
create or replace 
procedure myproc(
          id            in number 
        , optional_txt  in varchar2 default null 
        , random_pct   out number
        )
is 
begin
    random_pct := 101+id;      
end myProc;


declare 
   res  number;
begin
   myproc ( id         => 1
          , random_pct => res
          ); 
   dbms_output.put_line('res=' || to_char(res));
end;    

or even

declare 
   res  number;
begin
   myproc ( random_pct => res
          , id         => 2
          ); 
   dbms_output.put_line('res=' || to_char(res));
end;
```